# Подсчитать слова, которые начинаются на гласную

Tags: python

Провожу работу с подсчётом букв в питоне, но ломая голову не могу реализовать код так, чтобы считались все слова начинающиеся с гласной буквы, использовал `startswith()` и никак не получалось, решил сделать по-другому, но получается только рассчитать просто количество гласных, вот код:

```py
a = input('Введите любой текст: ')
b = input('Введите любые цифры: ')
word = 0
wordStart = 'aeiouy'
number = 0
countVowel = str(a.startswith(wordStart))
counts = str(countVowel)
for i in a:
    if (i.isalpha()) == False or True:
        word += 1
for i in b:
    if (i.isalnum()) == False or True:
        number += 1
print('Количество букв:', word)
print('Количество цифр:', number)
print(countVowel)
```

Comment: Это что вообще такое, как вы думаете, что вы тут проверяете `if (i.isalpha()) == False or True:`? )))

Answer (score 1):

Можно решить в одну строку

```py
countVowel = sum(1 for word in str_.split() if word[0] in wordStart)
```

Логика: создаем кортеж из значений `1`, где `1` записывается при условии, что нулевая буква (первая в привычном понимании) существует в последовательности определенной в переменной `wordStart`. В конце используем метод `sum()`, который суммирует все еденицы.

Что вы точно не учли, используя `startswith`, так это то, что вам нужно разделить строку по словам с помощью метода `split()`. Плюс аргументом вам нужно передать префикс, то есть конкретную букву, а не последовательность. Документация [здесь](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith)

Если сложно понять код в одну строку, здесь напишу проще (не является полным логическим эквивалентом для кода выше)

```py
countVowel= 0
words = a.split()
for word in words:
    if word[0] in wordStart:
        countVowel+= 1
```

Так же, желательно учитывать такие вещи, как строчные и прописные буквы, и приводить к одному виду

```py
a.lower().split()
```

Comment: Есть простое правило. Если вы где-то в условиях или вычислениях пишете `True` или `False` в явном виде - значит вы делаете что-то избыточное. Если вы всё-равно суммируете `True`, то можно упростить: `sum(word[0] in wordStart for word in str_.split())`. И да, если вы суммируете результат работы генераторного выражения, то лишние круглые скобки можно не писать. А если вы хотели, чтобы код был понятнее, и поэтому сделали вариант с `if`, то нужно было суммировать `1`, а не `True`, потому что такой трюк начинающим всё-равно будет непонятен.

Comment: @CrazyElf хорошо подмечено, но боялся быть не понятым со стороны ТС. Для меня понятно, что все что не пусто будет `True`. Дополню ответ чуть позже с пояснением.

Comment: Ещё раз. Если вы пишете код, понятный новичкам, то пишите `sum(1 for ...`, а если вы пользуетесь трюком с тем, что `True == 1`, то это уже код не для новичков и остальные попытки сделать код понятнее не имеют особого смысла.